# Display Ninja Tables meta data at the top of the table? Or is there a way to hide the table completely until fully loaded?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

when I use the shortcode:

[ninja_tables id="XXXXXX" info=' Current page: {CP} of {TP} , {TR} articles loaded' ]

the info meta box is displayed at the bottom of the table.
This is pretty sad, because I have a table with 60k+entires, and the user is not able to interact with it well unless everything is loaded.
Is there a way to display the data loading proces at the top of the table?
Or, is there a way to hide the whole table until it is fully loaded, and meanwhile display only the data loading process?
I am totally newbie.
Thanks

Comment: Please specify more and insert code using the code tag. Thanks.

Comment: hello, what specification do you need?